# Draggable background-image with background-size:cover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a fixed div that contains an image as a background like this

```
<div style='
     width:230px;
     height:230px;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-image:url(img/myimage.jpeg)
     background-size: cover;'></div>
```

The image overlaps the div-box.
The user should be able to drag the image and the new **background-position:** coordinates should be accessible somehow via jQuery just after the user releases the mouse. My aim is to create a very simple crap image effect just like in facebook:

[image]

How can I achive this? And is it even possible to show the overflowig background with background-size:cover?

Comment: Use firebug and move it, then you will see position

Comment: most of the images are 4:3 ratio, if you want to convert it 1:1 then you need to use ((3/4)* width of the image)=height of the image. and you need to decide width by yourself.

Comment: @MiomirDancevic I want to develop a front-end solution for users of my website

Answer (score 2):

You can use this [Plugin](https://github.com/kentor/jquery-draggable-background), and try

```
element.backgroundDraggable()
```

Here you have a [demo](http://kentor.me/jquery-draggable-background/)

Comment: The Plugin is not maintained anymore, but its defintly doing the right thing. I will check the js code and try to figure out how to output the background-position coordinates.

Comment: Also there seems no option to make the overflowing image visible through a transparent layer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the `mousemove` event on the div, and calculate the new `background-position` from there.

Here is an example to get you started: http://codepen.io/dghez/pen/ItxKE

To see if the left mouse button is pressed within the `mousemove` handler (to simulate a drag), check `e.buttons === 1` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousemove))

**Update:**

Modified `mousemove` handler from the example, which lets you drag the background (while annoyingly selecting the text at the same time...):

```
...
$(".title").mousemove(function(e) {
    if(e.buttons === 1) {
        mouseX = e.offsetX;
        mouseY = e.offsetY;
        traX = mouseX + 1640;
        traY = mouseY + 200;
        //console.log(traX, traY);
        $(".title").css({"background-position": traX + "px " + traY + "px"});
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is awesome. But two questions: 1) What to use instead of mousemove if I only want to move the elemnt when clicked and when the curser is in the image? 2) Could you explain why you calculate the new X position as  traX = ((4 * mouseX) / 570) + 40; ?

Comment: 1) You check the `e.buttons` property, which I mentioned in my answer. I have updated the answer with a `mousemove` handler that is closer to what you're trying to do. 2) That's not my code, it's just an example I found. But the .. * 4/570 just says how much the background should move compared to the mouse movement, and + 40 is the *offset* - it says where the background should be when the mouse is at coordinate (0,0). Again, my update should be closer to what you want.